# substr at Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

At Amazon Athena, I want to extract only the character string "2017-07-27" from the character string "2017-07-27 12:10:08".

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (event_datetime.s, 0, 10) FROM production limit 10
```

I tried it like this which only returns numbers 0 to 10.

At Athena, is it possible to cut character strings? If so, how can I do it?

Or, if you know how to cast "2017-07-27 12:10:08" to date type, that's fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

You can use SUBSTR to substring a column value.

Here is the [string function reference page](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html).

In your case, this would lead to the following statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(event_datetime.s, 1, 10) FROM production limit 10
```

*NOTE that the index position of the first character is 1 (not zero), the same as in standard SQL.*

Comment: strange how left() and right() don't work but this does

Comment: Note that the second parameter is a length, not the end position from a char-array perspective -- see substr(string, start, length) → varchar in the reference page in above answer ....